# how to implement a class that supports both stack and heap allocations

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++pmr

What is the most straightforward way of forcing `std::vector` to use a stack-based buffer? My guess is to use `std::pmr::vector`.

I want to write a class in a way that enables the use of both the normal vector (which uses dynamic allocations) and also one which uses a custom buffer.

Here is a sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory_resource>

// how should I implement this class? Using a template? How?
struct Foo
{
    explicit Foo( const std::size_t count = 1000, const char fillChar = ' ' )
    : vec( count, fillChar )
    {
    }

    std::pmr::vector<char> vec; // I need both normal and pmr vector
                                // (depending on what the client chooses to use)
};


int main( )
{
    std::array<std::byte, 10'000> buffer;
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource rsrc { buffer.data( ), 10'000 };
    std::pmr::vector<char> vec( 6000, '*', &rsrc ); // this free vector is a sample that
                                                    // shows how I may want to allocate
                                                    // a buffer for the vector member of Foo
    // print the content for demonstration
    std::copy_n( std::begin( vec ), 5, std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << '\n';


    // how should I achieve the above or something similar for this object
    Foo foo { 2000, '!' };
}
```

I would also want to mention that the aim is simplicity so I'll be glad to see a fairly simple approach. But any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood exactly but is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/o9E9cKqhb) something like what you have in mind?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Yes it seems reasonably simple. Thanks. Now I'm going to try it to see if it does the job.

Comment: Oh, great. If it works, you'll can write an answer to your own question if you wish. I'm off to bed :-)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Yes I'll write an answer. But now I'm stuck in passing the `rsrc` to the constructor of `Foo`. I did it. But then it made the `Foo<std::vector> x { 1000, '^' };` unusable. It resulted in an error. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rEcG8h13b).

Comment: Can you not just use `std::vector` with a custom allocator?

Comment: digito_evo:  I see... I've slept on it and added an idea as an answer. It's basically doing what @Taekahn suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to mimic the setup used by `vector` and the alias template `pmr::vector`:

```cpp
namespace foo {
  template <class Allocator = std::allocator<char>>
  struct Foo {
      using size_type = typename std::vector<char, Allocator>::size_type;

      constexpr Foo(size_type count, const char value,
                    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
          : vec(count, value, alloc) {}

      std::vector<char, Allocator> vec;
  };

  namespace pmr {
    using Foo = foo::Foo<std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char>>;
  }
}  // namespace foo
```

Using `foo::Foo` and `foo::pmr::Foo`:

```
int main() {
    foo::Foo x(1000, '^');

    std::array<std::byte, 10'000> buffer;
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource rsrc{buffer.data(), buffer.size()};   
    foo::pmr::Foo y(2000, '$', &rsrc);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P1nh7vnaM)